# How to parametrize off-shellness?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, virtual-particles, analyticity

The energy of a massive on-shell particle of mass $m$ and three-momentum $\vec{p}$ satisfies 
$$E_\vec{p} = \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}. $$

What would be the analogous expression for an off-shell particle? I've seen some write$^\dagger$

$$E_\vec{p} = \sqrt{\vec{p}^2+M^2} $$ for the energy of an off-shell particle, where $M$ denotes the *virtuality* of the particle. Since for an off-shell particle the momentum need not be fixed leads to the energy not needed to be fixed hence one could in principle use any function (that satisfies some conditions) that in a certain limit goes to the square root function. Is simplicity the reason one uses the square root function even in the off-shell case?

$----------$

$\dagger$ In real life, I cannot find an online reference at the moment.

Comment: What is the value of $M$ comparatively with $m$ ?

Comment: @Sofia I think that depends on the problem at hand, ie how off shell is reasonable for the problem at hand. I think one should integrate over it.

Comment: In other words, it's not fixed.

Comment: I believe that your question just passed unnoticed. Did you consider to call the attention of the moderators?

Comment: Yeah I will probably edit it or something sooner or later.